# IIS RewriteMaps to new URL including WWW and HTTPS

Tags: redirect, iis

I have the following Rule in my RewriteRules

```
<rule name="New URL redirects">
    <match url=".*"/>
    <conditions>
        <add input="{OldUrls:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)"/>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false"/>
</rule>
```

in my RewriteMaps i have the following

```
<rewriteMap name="OldUrls">
        <add key = "/SomeOldUrl" value = "/New/ShinyUrl" />
</rewriteMap>
```

I want to make sure that the new url is using **www** and **https** as part of the redirect, how do i add all of this into one rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try below rule:

```
 <rule name="Force WWW and SSL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]" />
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="www.sample1.com" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{OldUrls:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.sample1.com/{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
```

```
            <rewriteMap name="OldUrls">
                <add key="/s2" value="/s3" />
            </rewriteMap>
        </rewriteMaps>
```

[image]